# D3: Unable to append the labels to example's circle version

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Note: Please do not close this without guiding to appropriate place.
      Have tried almost every known solution so far

I've been trying to add labels to each node of the force directed graph as shown in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/bricof/5502b02332570c820e4a41db0b165089).

So far, I could add the labels to the force directed version of the diagram but when transformed to the circle variant, both nodes and labels on the node doesn't transition or transform. Please help me figure out what is it that I'm doing wrong and any suggestions to further improve it are also welcome.

Styles:

```
    node {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

   .link {
      stroke: #999;
    }
   .label {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
      fill: #000; 
      pointer-events: none; 
      stroke-width: 0;
    }
```

Node and text code:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
            .on("mouseover", fade(.1, true))
            .on("mouseout", undoFade())
          .call(force.drag);
    node.append("circle")
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
          .attr("r", 5);
 node.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("y", -22)
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

Node transform code:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Code for circle:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll('.node')
                .transition().duration(1000)
                  .attr('cx', function(d,i){ return x_scale(Math.sin(index_to_rad(i))); })
                  .attr('cy', function(d,i){ return y_scale(Math.cos(index_to_rad(i))); });
```

Comment: The issue is likely that you are modifying the cx and cy properties of a `g` element when creating the circle layout. This won't do anything to the position of each node, a cx and cy property exists for circles. There may be other issues, but it is hard to verify without the remainder of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing too much translation to your nodes. If you want to animate things change:

```
node
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

And modify the circle code to this:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll('.node');
```

This will translate both the circle (and label) in an animation, while keeping them aligned. Essentially you're double translating your circles at the moment away from the labels. Making this will leave your circle at the default `0,0` but the parent will already have been translated. Here's a diagram to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian, I solved it yesterday itself. Forgot to remove it.
I applied same logic for transition but for the whole group instead of node or circle.
`svg.selectAll('g')
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                  return "translate(" + (d.x) + "," + (d.y) + ")";
                });`

Even though I didn't make any changes to circle code, it works fine now!

Nice catch btw!